# Get first date of week from provided date

Tags: javascript, datetime

I want to pass a date object into a function and determine what the first date of that week was.

Example: If I pass in today's date (2009/06/24) I want the function to return what the first date of this week was, i.e. Sunday's date was 2009/06/21 so it must return that.

Anyone know of any standard javascript function that does that? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the answer on this question: [How do I get the first day of the previous week from a date object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605133/how-do-i-get-the-first-day-of-the-previous-week-from-a-date-object-in-javascript/605137)