# Get Last Day (Date) of Week for a given Date

Tags: java, datetime

How to get the last week Day (saturday) Date for a particular Date. Means if I give Input as `06-04-2012`

> (MM-dd-YYYY)

The output should be `06-09-2012` as seen in [this calendar](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/monthly.html?year=2012&month=6).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get first date of week from provided date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036613/get-first-date-of-week-from-provided-date)

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen The Question you linked is for JavaScript, not Java. So, not a duplicate.

Answer (score 7):

```
Calendar cal  = Calendar.getInstance();
int currentDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
int leftDays= Calendar.SATURDAY - currentDay;
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, leftDays);
```

See

- [example](http://ideone.com/9Q6wj)

Comment: If current day is a Saturday, this will return it as is.

Comment: unfortunately this only works for sunday - sat cals...what about other locales when the week starts with monday? a universal solution?

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse( 
    "06-04-2012" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM-dd-uuuu" ) 
).with( TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame( DayOfWeek.SATURDAY ) )
 .format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM-dd-uuuu" )  )
```

## Using java.time

The modern way is with java.time classes.

First [parse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-) your input string as a [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM-dd-uuuu" );
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "06-04-2012" , f );
```

> ld.toString(): 2012-06-04

Then get the next Saturday, or use the date itself if it is a Saturday. To specify a Saturday, use the enum [`DayOfWeek.SATURDAY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#SATURDAY). To find that next or same date that is a Saturday, use an implementation of [`TemporaAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) found in the [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) (note plural name) class.

```
LocalDate nextOrSameSaturday = 
    ld.with( TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame( DayOfWeek.SATURDAY ) ) ;
```

To generate a String, I suggest calling `toString` to use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```
String output = ld.toString();
```

> 2012-06-09

But if you insist, you may use the same formatter as used in parsing.

```
String output = ld.format( f );
```

> 06-09-2012

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Look at either JODA time or (if you cannot add new libraries) the Calendar class.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Calendar lastDayOfWeek(Calendar calendar){  
     Calendar cal = (Calendar) calendar.clone();  
     int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);  
     while(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SATURDAY){  
          cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, ++day);  
     }  
     return cal;  
}
```